# Phaser bars that grow independently and restart

Tags: phaser-framework

I've tried a few things but nothing solid enough to post. I'm trying to create a few bars (think mana and hp) that all grow at the same time but at different rates. Then when one has reach it's full size they would all stop and wait some sort of signal. After that it would reset back to zero and start again with all the other bars resuming their progress.

Even if I don't get code, concept is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're okay with a concept and didn't include your current code, I'll provide a concept answer. :)

One option:

1. Create variables to store current and maximum hp and mana (`currentHP`, `maximumHp`, `currentMana`, `maximumMana`).
2. In your state's `update` check if the current value of *both* hp and mana is less than the maximum. If they are you'll move onto step 3, otherwise you'll check to see if your signal is triggered. This could be as simple as just checking to see if a variable has been set.
3. Since neither the hp and mana values are at the maximum, you increase the current hp and mana values by whatever values are needed.